# Nunit-console3 default encoding

Tags: .net, nunit, nunit-console

I'm saving failed tests to file to rerun them again with `nunit-console3`. Looks like some tests which contains `TestCase` with Cyrillic characters in test case parameters are skipped. I looked at file and seams that encoding is quite strange. What is default `--encoding=...` parameter for `nunit-console3`?

I don't see this in documentation, maybe someone will know it.

Comment: Can you please post some code, e.g. the test cases you're using?

Comment: Try `--encoding=utf-8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default behaviour is to use the system default, the encoding is only changed if specifically specified via a command line flag.

See the source code, here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/blob/91ef2ae1b1077ad450d27667c6c4b3ec84b8cdf5/src/NUnitConsole/nunit3-console/Program.cs#L68

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Options.ConsoleEncoding))
        {
            try
            {
                Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(Options.ConsoleEncoding);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                WriteHeader();
                OutWriter.WriteLine(ColorStyle.Error, string.Format("Unsupported Encoding, {0}", error.Message));
                return ConsoleRunner.INVALID_ARG;
            }
        }
```